# Where is the mongo database created when using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new at node js and mongo db.
To create a db I do:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb"
mongo.connect(db, function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    db.close();
});
```

In which folder is mydb created?

Comment: That is an attempt to establish a connection with MongoDB, not creating a new DB.

When you say folder, I assume you mean URL/Path?

Answer (score 0):

The command `require('mongodb').MongoClient` creates a Client that connects to an existing Mongo database. The database does not exist.

[Follow these instructions here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/) to create a new MongoDB instance, which you can then connect to.